# Jasper Report export to xls (RTL)

Tags: jasper-reports, right-to-left, xlsx

I am trying to export excel jasper report in RTL mode.It does not appear that my report properties are working correctly.
In this report I am using the below property to direct my excel sheet ti RTL.

```html
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xlsx.sheet.direction=RTL
```

I tried another way too:

```js
 exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
 exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
 SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
 configuration.setSheetDirection(RunDirectionEnum.RTL);
 exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
```

None of the above solutions are working. Please,somebody help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `xlxs` does not support the sheet RTL, you can use `xlx` as below:

```
exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
SimpleXlsReportConfiguration xlsReportConfig = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
xlsReportConfig.setSheetDirection(RunDirectionEnum.RTL);
exporter.setConfiguration(xlsReportConfig);
```

The issue  has been raised at: http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/6566